# How can I find height of Dome other than centre in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry

I have generated this 3D dome surface using MATLAB using the SURF command. I need to find the height (Z) of the dome at parts other than center (Like for example at (X=-2000, Y=-2000, Z=?)). How can I achieve that using MATLAB? See the image below for ref:

[image]

Comment: How did you generate this plot? You have the data, not us!

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere : `(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r^2`

The centre of the sphere is at <0,0,0> and r=3000 so this is the equation: `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3000^2`

You have x and y and want to find z.

`z^2 = 3000^2 - (x^2 + y^2)`

```
Sqrt (3000^2 - (2000^2+2000^2))
```

> 1.06

Does not seem like a question for SO.